# Django new project ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoapp' (virtual env's name)

Tags: django

I am trying to start a new Django project but running into the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<XYZ>'` where `XYZ` is the name of my virtual environment created using `mkvirtualenv`. This is really weird and I can't say what has changed in my system recently to cause this.

Here are steps showing how this error occurs in a brand new project:

1. Create the virtual environment:

```
~/code/projects/temp$ mkvirtualenv demoapp
created virtual environment CPython3.9.6.final.0-64 in 237ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/ankush/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.3, setuptools==51.3.3, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/get_env_details
```

2. Install Django:

```
(demoapp) ~/code/projects/temp$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-4.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.4.1
  Using cached asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, asgiref, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.4.1 django-4.0 sqlparse-0.4.2
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

3. Start a new project

```
(demoapp) ~/code/projects/temp$ django-admin startproject uberclone
```

4. Run the new project right away:

```
(demoapp) ~/code/projects/temp$ cd uberclone/
(demoapp) ~/code/projects/temp/uberclone$ ./manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 66, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 73, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoapp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankush/code/projects/temp/uberclone/./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ankush/code/projects/temp/uberclone/./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 386, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/ankush/.virtualenvs/demoapp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demoapp'
```

I feel like there's something really dumb I'm missing, but can't seem to find it. Please help!

=== Edit 1: Adding `manage.py` contents ===

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'uberclone.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of the generated `manage.py`?

Comment: Thanks. You haven't set the env var `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` have you? Can check the output of `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Comment: @IainShelvington So, first of all, I just tried the `python3 -m venv` approach and got it working. I think `mkvirtualenv` is misconfigured somehow on my system. Second, `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` gives blank output, but if you want to drop this investigation, please feel free. :-)